# Android - Soft keyboard for TextField inside a webview

Tags: android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Usually in landscape mode an EditText will open the IME in full screen mode, but for an textfield inside a webview (loaded as a HTML content) it doesn't and it pushes the existing view upwards. Tried using 'adjustpan' options but to no avail. Is it possible to change the IME in this scenario?   Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

'adjustPan' might not work unless you specify the option for all of the views in the tree, not just the activity.  Take a look at this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183626/758458

Comment: Is it possibly to also do this programatically for all the views?