# Textbox hidden below keyboard in Android XWalkView or WebView

Tags: android, input, webview, android-softkeyboard, xwalkview

**Edit:** this also adjust to webview!

I use XWalkView of corsswalk in my android app. In the XWalkView there are many inputs in it. When I input something for the input at the bottom , the soft keyboard covers it.
I  use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the activity,

or in addition add `android:isScrollContainer="true"` in the xwalkview,

But neither works.

And help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you check with this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

Comment: I have not tryed that, I Will check it.

Comment: i had a similar problem, i solve it by hackish method like when edit text gets focus i made top views above it Visibility gone and added a onfocus change listner for edit text, and on focus changes hide keyboard and make above views visibility Visible

Comment: @Redman currently I add some padding at the bottom of the page. But there is some white space, seems not well.

Comment: @Ironman I checked it, it works. Will you make it an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox hidden below keyboard in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026854/textbox-hidden-below-keyboard-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

you have use this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of work! I get this:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` works for android native Edittext, but not for webview or xwalkview.

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or not set this setting will works for webview or xwalkview.