# No behavior using adjustResize with iframe webview Android

Tags: android, iframe, webview, android-manifest, adjustpan

The input field is hidden by the virtual keyboard. Nothing change using adjustResize or adjustPan in manifest. The input field in inside a container, an Iframe. Maybe the iframe is the problem but I'm not sure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox hidden below keyboard in Android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026854/textbox-hidden-below-keyboard-in-android-webview)

Comment: I tested this but same thing