# Android keyboard hides input in web view

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, field, show-hide

In an Android webview, when a text/password field is touched, the keyboard appears but covers the field, forcing the user to scroll to see what they are typing.

Is there a way to solve this issue or a way to have an auto-focus in web view ? (as seen in iOS).

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dedalos.amb">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/splash_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/ambWebViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/splash_background" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I also paste styles and colors here:

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>

    <color name="splash_background">#e11020</color>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#e11020</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#e11020</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#e11020</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

    </style>

    <!-- SplashTheme -->
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_theme</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026854/textbox-hidden-below-keyboard-in-android-webview

Answer (score 8):

Try adding the following property:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the root LinearLayout of the  .xml layout.

Comment: And navigation bar is colored too!  I can't use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` as long as I don't understand how to make status bar and navigation bar transparent again 

Comment: You can use a CoordinatorLayout as your activity root view and then setFitsSystemWindows(boolean) will work. You can check the following post for a detailed explaination. [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec?) @Stefano.

Comment: @Stefano Also you may try alternative solutions if you do not want to change your layout. They can be found in this  answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026854/textbox-hidden-below-keyboard-in-android-webview)

Comment: unfortunately my app crashes with CoordinatorLayout instead of LinearLayout :-/

Answer (score 3):

Android keyboard hides when the app use full screen mode.

This issue can be resolved if you use

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` in your styles.

then use `<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">`

in your manifest.

Comment: great solution on fullscreen this was not working. but when I disable the fullscreen this works without need to change on manifest. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this article:
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility

Maybe this will help you.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for helping! I tried to insert it in the .MainActivity and unfortunately it doesn't work :-( the keyboard appears and covers the text field

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by following answers

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in root LinearLayout @animeshk

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` in theme style @Nawin

In my case, it worked well without adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following property:

- In manifest file where you register your activity :

  ```
  <activity android:name="yourActivity"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are two Alternatives:

**Alternative 1 :**

For single line to focus then use this:

```
webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

**Alternative 2 :**

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.requestFocusFromTouch();  
                break;
        }               
        return false;
    }

});
```

I hope it'll help you...!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('[your view name without square brackets]')[0].focus();");
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```